# Passing and using dinamically arguments in python functions

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, wrapper

I do have a function that receives a list and some parameters, later this function creates a linear equation from the parameters and the list provided.

```py
def modelFunction(data, a, b, c, offset):
    f = (data[0] * a) + (data[1] * b) + (data[2] * c) + offset
    return f
```

I would like to create the parameters dinamically and create the linear equation dinamically also.
The final objective should be that I can create a different function with a different number of parameters every time I call it.
Example:
If I need to create a linear equation with 2 parameters and it's intercept then it creates a function like:

## data is a list of len=2

```py
def modelFunction(data, a, b,offset):
    f = (data[0] * a) + (data[1] * b) + offset
    return f
```

If I need to create a linear equation with 3 parameters and it's intercept then it creates a function like:

## data is a list of len=3

```py
def modelFunction(data, a, b, c, offset):
    f = (data[0] * a) + (data[1] * b) + (data[2] * c) + offset
    return f
```

I believe the * operator might help me but hadn't been able to figure it out

Comment: Why don't you pass a, b, c, and so on as a tuple or something that you can iterate through?

Comment: It's a requirement by other procedures that uses the modelFunction() function, it's parameters and it's offset to make regressions, clusterings, optimization and so on

Answer (score 0):

Equal length checking omitted for brevity:

```
def modelFunction(data, *coeffs):
    return sum(d * c for d, c in zip(data, coeffs)) + coeffs[-1]
```